# If I store data using Xamarin.Essentials Preferences, can I retrieve that data to modify text color on an iOS LaunchScreen.Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

If using Xamarin.Essentials Preferences class to store application preferences in a key/value store.

`Preferences.Set("my_key", "my_value");`

Then can I get this back as my iOS application starts in time to modify the color of some text I have on the LaunchScreen.Storyboard and if so how can I do this.

Please NOTE, there's a similar question / answer on SO that's now over 9 years old with an answer pointing to links that no longer exist.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is it for light and dark mode? Because you’re gonna have a launch screen that takes you to the splash screen, and users want know of the transition https://www.raywenderlich.com/4503153-how-to-create-a-splash-screen-with-swiftui

Comment: My splash screen can be dark or light.  If possible I would like a launch screen that appears a matching color even if only for a second.

Comment: The only thing you can make dynamic for the launch screen is to react to the dark and light mode. Have you looked into this blog? https://codetraveler.io/2019/10/11/creating-a-dark-mode-splash-screen/

Answer (score 1):

Impossible , we can't handle any logic in code behind with launch screen .

In other word , the view(UI elements) you set in launch screen storyboard must be static , can't be changed.

Comment: Is it possible to change which launch screen might appear then?

Comment: No possible either

Comment: As saamer said , the color can be only changed depends on light/dark mode ,nothing else.